# problema al guardar respuesta con axios

Tags: javascript, axios

Quiero guardar la respuesta que retorna con una petición axios en una variable local y retornarla. Lo he intentado hacer de varias formas y nada. De que manera pudiera hacerlo?
Aquí tienen un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer y mensajes para depurarlo.

```js
function getUser(username) {
        let user = null;
        axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + username)
            .then(response => {
                user = response.data.login;
                console.log("dentro de axios: " + user);
            });
        console.log("dentro de 'getUser': " + user);
        return user;
    }
    console.log("llamando la funcion: " + getUser('ragnarok22'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: El proceso está bien, lo que debes evaluar es la respuesta que te llega, pon un `console.log(response)` dentro de tu `then` para que veas la estrucutra de la respuesta, es probable que la llave `data` no exista.

Comment: Ya lo comprobé y de hecho si está. Siempre retorna con la llave `data` aunque en el servidor retorne un error. Y tambien comprobé que exista `login`. Si lo corres puedes ver que dentro del `then` retorna valores con `console.log` pero fuera no modifica los valores de la variable local `user`

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en el único lugar donde está disponible `users` (con datos) es dentro del callback, la única forma de mantener la sintaxis que tienes para que te funcionen todos los console.log's es envolviendo todo dentro de una función `async` y hacer un `await` dentro:

```js
(async() => {

  async function getUser(username) {
    let user = null;
    await axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + username)
      .then(response => {
        user = response.data.login;
        console.log("dentro de axios: " + user);
      });
    console.log("dentro de 'getUser': " + user);
    return user;
  }

  console.log("llamando la funcion: " + await getUser('ragnarok22'));

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```